# Setting path in bash_profile

Tags: unix, terminal, bash

Why does setting a `PATH` require the `:${PATH}` at the end?

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

When I append a path to this I would do

```
PATH=$PATH:...
```

How do I append a `PATH` without going to a new line. That is, how would I append a `PATH` to the original `PATH` statement.

If I wanted to put the following all in the first line, for instance. How does this interact with the `:${PATH}` part?

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a difference between appending an existing path to the front or the end of the `$PATH` environment variable. The way bash resolves execution paths is by starting from the front of the list. That means if you have these two directories in your path:

```
PATH="/dir1/bin:/dir2/bin"
```

And they both have the executable `test.sh` in it, then when you run `test.sh`, it'll execute the one in `/dir1/bin/test.sh` since that directory appears first in the path.

Additionally, `${PATH}` is the same as `$PATH`.

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

is simply adding `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` *to the front of the path* and

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

is simply adding `/usr/local/mysql/bin` *to the end of the path*.

So how do you do both in one line? Something like this:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```