# Drush can't connect to local MySQL through socket on WAMP

Tags: mysql, drupal, cygwin, wamp, drush

*I asked this on [drupal.stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130066/drush-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-through-socket-on-wamp), but it seems like the question relates more to Cygwin and WAMP, so I'm reposting here.

Trying to set up Drush with in a local dev environment on Windows 7 and can't get MySQL properly configured. A test command I've been running via Cygwin, with the resulting error, is as follows:

```
$ drush sql-query "SELECT * FROM erg_node WHERE nid=3"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can run the same SQL statement in phpmyadmin and it works fine. I can run the same drush command with a remote site and it also works, so it seems like it must be related to how MySQL is configured with WAMP and Cygwin. When I check `which mysql` via Cygwin, I get back `/usr/bin/mysql` instead of the path for WAMP's mysql. But the WAMP mysql path is set in my system environment PATH variable, so it should be accessible.

I've tried changing my.ini to include `host = 127.0.0.1`, copied the my.ini file to /etc/my.cnf, and run `chmod -R 755 /tmp/`. The my.ini file already included `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock`, and I tried adding a symlink i.e. `ln -s /cygdrive/c/wamp/tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

*Edit - the drush command above executes properly within Powershell, so it seems like the issue is that Cygwin is using `/usr/bin/mysql` instead of the WAMP mysql command. Is there a way to change which mysql command Cygwin uses?

Comment: Have you checked the points outlined in this article?
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add the path to the version of mysql that I wanted to use (the WAMP version) to the beginning of my PATH variable in my `.bash_profile`, so obvious in retrospect! [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231286/setting-path-in-bash-profile) regarding PATH variable in `.bash_profile`.